# Transform a Table (2 dimensions) in a vector(1 dimension) in R

Tags: r, histogram

I want to turn some data looking like this :

[image]
which is in a txt file looking like this :

```
tailles en centimetres           
151 163 165 168 170 173 175 179          
152 163 165 168 171 173 175 179     
157 164 166 169 172 174 176 180     
159 164 166 169 172 174 176 180     
160 164 167 169 172 174 177 181     
160 164 167 169 172 174 177 181     
160 164 167 169 173 174 177 181     
161 164 168 169 173 175 178 181     
161 165 168 170 173 175 178 186    
162 165 168 170 173 175 179 187
```

into this :

```
title : "tailles en centimetres" (the first line of the file)     
data : 151  163 165 168 170 173 175 179 152 163 165 168 171 173 175 179 157 164 166 169 172 174 176 180 159 164 166 169 172 174 176 180 160 164 167 169 172 174 177 181 160 164 167 169 172 174 177 181 160 164 167 169 173 174 177 181 161 164 168 169 173 175 178 181 161 165 168 170 173 175 178 186 162 165 168 170 173 175 179 187 (a one line numeric piece of data)
```

I will then use this to trace an histogram using :

```
hist(data,main=title)
```

I used this which basically keeps only the first column of data converts it into a "numerical" type of data and then turns it into one histogram.

```
a=read.table("data.txt")
a<-as.numeric(a[1,])
hist(a)
```

Comment: You can simply convert `a` to a matrix: `m <- as.matrix(a)`, then convert `m` to a vector: `v <- as.vector(m)`, then `hist(v)`.

Comment: The problems concerns the title how do i extract it from the matrix ? Because my goal is as stated display the title which was in the file @SteveM